# Codemirror Autocomplete hidden behind bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I am having an issue with codemirror autocomplete in bootstrap modal, it gets hidden behind the modal. So it works but doesn't appear in top.

So far i have tried using css modifications such as:

```
.codeMirror-hints, .CodeMirror-hint, .CodeMirror-hint-active { 
    z-index:2147483647 !important;
    position:relative !important;
    background:white!important; 
}
```

but anything like this solution is not working, tried both

> position : absolute

and

> position : relative

but no luck.
I am using bootstrap 3.0 and codemirror 5.20.0 if that helps. The annoying thing with codemirror is that autocomplete goes away as soon as i try to do inspect element.
I am using Chrome latest Build and Firefox both with same problem.

Edit:

the following is the code for codemirror on modal show:

```
$('#cssModal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
            var textArea = document.getElementById('pageCss');
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea, {
                theme: 'monokai',
                extraKeys: { "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete" },
                mode:{name: "text/css", globalVars: true},
                lineNumbers: true,
                htmlMode:true
            }); 
        });
```

following is the modal popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cssModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cssModal-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="cssModal-label">@("<style>")</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea name="page_css" id="pageCss" class="form-control addon" rows="10">@Html.Raw(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.page_css) ? Model.page_css : " ")</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">@("</style>")</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the codemirror plugin sequence

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/addon/hint/show-hint.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/addon/hint/xml-hint.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/addon/hint/html-hint.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/addon/hint/css-hint.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/mode/css/css.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.10.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/2.36.0/formatting.min.js"></script>
```

FYI: i am using asp.net mvc, if that helps.

Comment: Did you include `show-hint.css`? Do you have css rules affecting bootstrap-modal? I tried locally and I solved your issue adding `.CodeMirror-hints{z-index: 1000000;}` to my style. Maybe you can add more code showing your imports and your codemirror code.

Comment: i will add code soon , but i have all the plugins added and they are working  in non modal elements so its not an plugin issue. i also traced the popup behind the modal , so its clearly a z-index problem.

Comment: i have updated the code, i am still having this issue . maybe this code will give you deeper insight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally made it working, never thought that class name case-sensitivity could be an issue in css, i just had to replace

> .codeMirror-hints

To

> .CodeMirror-hints

what a weird thing to happen.

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote if you are using lint ina bootstrap modal window , it will work but the message will appear behind the window. in the lint.css file search for this
`.CodeMirror-lint-tooltip` 
and in the z-index modify it accordingly.
This post put me in the right direction, thanks!!